Flutter - How to Add Sign in with Apple without XCode
Any tutorial i follow asks me to go to Capabilities on XCode to add the capability. Is there any manual code i can add to enable this if not using a mac.
After you add the capability, Xcode updates the target’s entitlements to include the Sign in with Apple Entitlement — an array that contains a single string of Default, the value that represents normal operation. If you configure Xcode to automatically manage app signing, then at this point, Xcode also enables Sign in with Apple for your app’s App ID in the developer portal.

Developing for Apple devices in all practicality requires owning of one or more Apple devices. That's Apple's choice, since they invented that particular instance of the technology.
